# Angular : Error: Uncaught (in promise) at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm upgrading from **Angular 4.0.0** to **Angular 5.2.6**

i'm facing some problem to get lazy module loading working.

with **angular 4.0.0** , it works fine , but now , with **5.2.6** , i getting such an error when clicking my redirecting button :

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:27), <anonymous>:13:34)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6558)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6542)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:27), <anonymous>:13:34)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6558)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6542)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
```

**my routing file looks like this :**

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        ....
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: 'app/home/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin]
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**suggestions ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have resolved this issue by upgrading mt **angular-cli** locally in the devDependenices (package.json) from **1.2.0** to **1.6.7**

Answer (score 41):

Do not import your lazy loaded module within your main app.module.ts. This will cause a circular dependency and throw the error you are receiving.

Comment: Then there will be no error and the routes are not changed to the targeted module..! I mean nothing will happen.

Comment: @RohitSharma a lazy loaded module is loaded into the Angular Injector when it's in fact "lazily loaded" at run time. Not including it within your main app.module.ts allows the module and it's dependencies to load in when the user clicks the route. This syntax `app/home/admin/admin.module#AdminModule` is the road to that implementation.

Answer (score 19):

I have changed the order of imports in my `app.module.ts` as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters)

So you need to have it for example like this:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HeroesModule,
  AppRoutingModule
]
```

The most important is to have First `BrowserModule` and at the end `AppRoutingModule`.

Comment: Wow, this resolved the issue for me. However, the problem only surfaced after upgrading the CLI.

Comment: It resolved for me. I was not having browser module & did not need it. Most important thing was to keep routing at end

Answer (score 14):

**Solution 1**

Imports order does matter so `import lazy loaded module` in top and `router module` in the last place. Because we are doing lazy loading, that lazy-loaded module has to exist before we do routing.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,       
    HeroModule, // Lazy-loaded module

    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

**Solution 2**

Usually `Angular CLI` will import the `module` to `app-module` when it was generated. so make sure `lazy-loaded` module was not imported in `app-module`

Comment: That's true. Thank's.

Answer (score 12):

I'm experiencing the same issue. This could be a bug with the angular-cli. I'm still not sure whether the bug is in the cli or in our code! As mentioned by [Gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298872/gerrit) it's still possible to compile with aot:
`ng serve --aot`

I've also resolved the issue by downgrading my angular-cli from **1.7.2** to **1.6.8**, which is the last CLI-Version which seems to work in our case.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9488#issuecomment-368871510 it seems to work with `ng serve --aot`

Answer (score 7):

`ng service --aot` while it compiles your code, is not a solution, it's just a coverup.
If you determined that it was not the CLI version try the below solution.

What you need to do is make sure in your `app.module.ts` you are not loading your lazy loaded module.

For instance:

```
app.module.ts
 imports: [
   ...
   AppRouterModule,
   FormsModule,
   YourFeatureModule, <--- remove this
   ...
 ]
```

Make sure `YourFeatureMOdule` is being loaded via the `routes`
ie:

```
app-routing.module.ts
 loadChildren: '../app/feature.module#YourFeatureModule'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue but simply restarting the nodes server (ng s) did the trick for me.

As a rule of thumb: if angular starts behaving strange, first try to restart your nodes server

Answer (score 3):

Was facing the same issue. Restarting the angular server `ng-serve` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use ng serve --aot instead. It is usually Angular CLI that added the lazy-loaded Angular module to AppModule when it was generated.