# Angular 5 Update breaks lazy loading of modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lazy-loading, angular5, angular-router

We have just upgraded our application from Angular **4** to Angular **5.2.6**
The application was built with Angular CLI and CLI recently updated to 1.6.8.

Our application uses lazy loading for some modules. This used to work perfectly with Angular 4, but we are now seeing some strange behaviour.

The application is split into two areas (modules) on of which is 'admin'.
The admin module is then also split into modules, one of which is loaded synchronously, the rest lazy.

The issue is with the lazy loaded module: UsersModule.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    redirectTo: '/admin/requests',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthAdminGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'requests',
        // syncrhronous because we always hit this route first
        loadChildren: () => RequestsModule, 
        data: { title: 'Requests' }
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule',
        data: { title: 'Users' }
      },
```

When the application is built a chunk is created for the users module.
[image: Chunk is built]

When the user navigates to the **'admin.users'** path the application loads the chunk into the head of the page and it is available in the browser source explorer.

[image: chunk loaded into head]

BUT the application does not load the module, instead an error is displayed in the console.

`Error: Cannot find 'UsersModule' in './users/users.module'`

[image: Cannot find 'UsersModule']

> BUT if we remove the module name #UsersModule

I.e. if the module routing is updated from

```
   {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule',
        data: { title: 'Users' }
      },
```

to

```
  {
            path: 'users',
            loadChildren: './users/users.module',
            data: { title: 'Users' }
          },
```

The application reloads and **now** users module is loaded correctly...??

But if we first start with this configuration, no chunk is created for users module...???

**NOTE**
Lazy loaded modules are NOT Imported into parent module.

**EDIT**
Package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.6",
    "@cloudinary/angular-5.x": "^1.0.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.14",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
    "angularfire2": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "cloudinary": "^1.9.0",
    "cloudinary-core": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "4.1.2",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^2.0.1",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "husky": "^0.15.0-rc.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "prettier": "1.10.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.4.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
```

Comment: This is a bit of a guess. Try changing your `loadChildren` path from `'./users/users.module#UsersModule'` to `'app/users/users.module#UsersModule'` (app in front). I know this shouldn't matter, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Get the same behaviour as above.

Comment: Can you show your package.json file?. Did you have a look here too? https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/1936

Comment: Yes, have looked through that. We are currently not ejected though (cli) and would prefer to stay that way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not import UsersModule in Parent Module. If you are using lazy loading then import is unnecessary and will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Angular CLI v1.7.x.  I hope it's being worked on, but there are several bug reports found at the official GitHub repo (eg. [Issue #9825](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9825)).

I'm not sure if you are having problems with the dev server or the production build, but I personally have trouble loading the dev server using `ng serve`.  However, I was able to fix this using `ng serve --aot`.  My production build works fine (`ng build --prod`).  This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991372/angular-error-uncaught-in-promise-at-webpackasynccontext-eval-at-src/49135044#49135044) was where I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, this was because the BrowserModule was declared in the main module and in the one that i wanted to lazy loading.