# Angular 7.1 after migration from 6.4.1 get `Uncaught (in promise): Error: There exists no control with id: name`

Tags: angular

After migrating to 6.4.1, the first component loading works fine, but on any click on another route, I get this error: Same problem with version 7.1

### Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 6.4.1
Node: 11.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.5
```

### Error

```
    An error occurred msg: Uncaught (in promise): Error: There exists no control with id: name
    Error: There exists no control with id: name
        at DynamicFormInstancesService.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormInstancesService.removeFormControlInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:125447:19)
        at DynamicMaterialFormControlContainerComponent.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormControlContainerComponent.removeInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:123112:41)
        at DynamicMaterialFormControlContainerComponent.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormControlContainerComponent.destroyFormControlComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:122806:18)
        at DynamicMaterialFormControlContainerComponent.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormControlContainerComponent.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:122621:14)
        at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:55903:18)
        at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:55871:13)
        at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:55861:29)
        at destroyView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56923:5)
        at callViewAction (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57049:13)
        at execEmbeddedViewsAction (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56992:17) Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: There exists no control with id: name
    Error: There exists no control with id: name
        at DynamicFormInstancesService.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormInstancesService.removeFormControlInstance (core.js:10115)
        at DynamicMaterialFormControlContainerComponent.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormControlContainerComponent.removeInstance (core.js:7780)
        at DynamicMaterialFormControlContainerComponent.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormControlContainerComponent.destroyFormControlComponent (core.js:7474)
        at DynamicMaterialFormControlContainerComponent.push../node_modules/@ng-dynamic-forms/core/fesm5/core.js.DynamicFormControlContainerComponent.ngOnDestroy (core.js:7289)
        at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22412)
        at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:22380)
        at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:22370)
        at destroyView (core.js:23432)
        at callViewAction (core.js:23558)
        at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23501)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
        at zone.js:892
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
        at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
        at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
        at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
```

### HTML (src/app/components/branch/branch-list/branch-list.component.html)

```
<div class="entitiesArray">
<h2 i18n>{{entitiesListTitle}}
    <span ngif="dataSource.entitiesCount() > 0">({{dataSource.entitiesCount()}})</span>
    <span class="actions">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="delete" (click)="sampleAddButtonClicked()">
        Add Samples
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="selectionModel && selectionModel.hasValue()" color="primary" class="delete"
        (click)="buttonRemoveSelectedRowsClicked($event)">
        Remove Selected Rows
    </button>
    <button matTooltip="Refresh" mat-icon-button (click)="onReloadClicked($event)" [disabled]="refreshButtonDisabled">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="refresh" class="mat-icon-">Refresh</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
    </span>
</h2>
<div id="pageContent">
    <div class="entitiesList">
    <div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async">
        <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>
    <div class="entitiesTable">
        <mat-table class="branch-list-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="id"
        matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
        <!-- Checkbox Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? buttonMasterToggleClicked() : null" [checked]="selectionModel.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                [indeterminate]="selectionModel.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
            </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selectionModel.toggle(row) : null"
                [checked]="selectionModel.isSelected(row)">
            </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!--Id Column-->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>#</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let entity">{{entity.id}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!--Name Column-->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell class="name-cell" *matCellDef="let entity">{{entity.name}} &nbsp;(<a routerLink="/ConsumptionSector">Consumption
                sectors</a>)</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Header -->
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsArray; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
        <!--Content-->
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsArray" (click)="onRowClicked(row)" [ngClass]="{ 'selected': currentEntity!==null && row!==null && row.id === currentEntity.id }"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <!--Paginator-->
        <mat-paginator [pageSize]="30" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 30]"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entitiesOperations">
    <form [formGroup]="entityAddFormGroup">
        <h2 i18n>Add</h2>
        <dynamic-material-form [group]="entityAddFormGroup" [model]="entityAddFormCtlModelArray"></dynamic-material-form>
        <button (click)="buttonAddEntityClicked(entityAddFormGroup.value)">Add</button>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <form *ngIf="entityEditFormGroup && currentEntity" [formGroup]="entityEditFormGroup">
        <h2 i18n>Edit #{{currentEntity.id}}</h2>
        <dynamic-material-form [group]="entityEditFormGroup" [model]="entityEditFormCtlModelArray"></dynamic-material-form>
        <button (click)="buttonEditEntityClicked(entityEditFormGroup.value)">Save</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
/**
Table
 */
mat-table.branch-list-table {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
  clear: both;
}
.mat-row,
.mat-header-row {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 1.1em;
  padding: 0.2px;
}
.mat-header-row {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.mat-cell {
  padding: 0.1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

/**
Columns
 */

mat-header-cell.mat-header-cell {
  padding: 2px;
  /*border: 1px solid #0f0;*/
}

/* SELECTION */
mat-cell.cdk-column-select,
mat-header-cell.cdk-column-select {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
}

/*ID*/
mat-cell.mat-column-id,
mat-header-cell.mat-column-id,
mat-cell:first-child, mat-footer-cell:first-child, mat-header-cell:first-child,
mat-header-cell.mat-column-select {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}

mat-cell.mat-cell {
  /*border: 1px solid #00f;*/
}
```

### other inherited css

```
/*---------- Entities Arrays -----------*/

div.entitiesArray {
}
div.entitiesArray h2 {
/*margin-block-start: 0;
margin-block-end: 0;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;*/
display: flex;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
div.entitiesArray h2 span {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0;
}
div.entitiesArray h2 span.actions {
margin-left: 50px;
flex: 10;
text-align: right;
font-size: 0.5em;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

span.actions button,
span.actions mat-form-field {
margin-left: 5px;
}
span.actions span.mat-button-wrapper{
    color: #000;
}

/* ---------- PageContent ------------- */

#pageContent {
    display: flex;
}

div.entitiesList {
    flex: 1;
}
div.entitiesOperations {
    border-left: 2px dotted #C88A36;
    flex: 0 0 300px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}


.selected {
background-color: rgba(251, 199, 7, 0.9);
}


/* ---------- Operations ------------- */



div.entitiesOperations div.submit {
text-align: center;
}

hr.verticalSeparator {
}

button.delete {
}


/**
Columns
*/

mat-header-cell.mat-header-cell {
padding: 2px;
/*border: 1px solid #0f0;*/
}

/* SELECTION */
mat-cell.cdk-column-select,
mat-header-cell.cdk-column-select {
flex: 0 0 40px;
/*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
}

/*ID*/
mat-cell.mat-column-id,
mat-header-cell.mat-column-id,
mat-cell:first-child, mat-footer-cell:first-child, mat-header-cell:first-child,
mat-header-cell.mat-column-select {
flex: 0 0 40px;
}

mat-cell.mat-cell {
/*border: 1px solid #00f;*/
}
```

### BranchListComponent extends EntityListComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BranchService} from '../../../services/branch.service';
import {LoggerService} from '../../../logger/logger.service';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {MessageService} from '../../../services/message.service';

import {DynamicFormControlModel, DynamicFormService, DynamicInputModel} from '@ng-dynamic-forms/core';
import {EntityListComponent} from '../../Entities/entity-list.component';
import {Branch} from '../../../entities/branch';
import {Constants} from '../../../Constants';
import { ConsumptionSectorService } from 'src/app/services/consumption.sector.service';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DBEntity } from 'src/app/entities/d-b-entity';
import { CompanyService } from 'src/app/services/company.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-branch-list',
templateUrl: './branch-list.component.html',
styleUrls: [
    './branch-list.component.css',
    '../../entities-list.component.css'
]
})
export class BranchListComponent extends EntityListComponent<Branch> {

displayedColumnsArray = ['select', 'id', 'name']; // Gives the order of the columns

constructor(
    protected router: Router,
    public messageService: MessageService,
    protected logger: LoggerService,
    protected route: ActivatedRoute,
    protected entitiesService: BranchService,
    protected childService: ConsumptionSectorService,
    protected parentService: CompanyService,
    protected formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public formService: DynamicFormService,
    iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    // private location: Location
) {
    super(router, messageService, logger, route, entitiesService, formBuilder, formService, iconRegistry, sanitizer, new Branch());
}



public ngAfterContentInit() {
    super.ngAfterContentInit()
    this.loadEntities(this.parentService)
}

/**
* Common to add and edit forms
*
* @param aStrangeObject
*/
protected _getCommonFormControlModel(aStrangeObject: Branch): DynamicFormControlModel[] {
    let lEntity: Branch = new Branch().deserialize(aStrangeObject)
    console.debug('-----getAddFormControlModel->aStrangeObject, lEntity:', aStrangeObject, lEntity)
    //Add form fields
    const result: DynamicFormControlModel[] = [
    new DynamicInputModel({
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        maxLength: 255,
        value: lEntity.name,
        placeholder: 'Sample input'
    }),
    ];

    return result
}

/**
* called by SelectableEntitiesListComponent->onInit
*
* @param aStrangeObject
*/
protected _getAddFormControlModel(aStrangeObject: Branch): DynamicFormControlModel[] {
    //console.debug('getAddFormControlModel->aStrangeObject:', aStrangeObject)
    let lEntity: Branch = new Branch().deserialize(aStrangeObject)
    console.debug('-----getAddFormControlModel->aStrangeObject, lEntity:', aStrangeObject, lEntity)
    //Add form fields
    const result: DynamicFormControlModel[] = this._getCommonFormControlModel(aStrangeObject)
    return result
}



/**
* Built onRowClicked
*
* @param anId
* @param aStrangeObject can be a row of dataTable
*/
protected _getEditFormControlModel(aStrangeObject: Branch): DynamicFormControlModel[] {
    console.log('getEditFormControlModel:', aStrangeObject)
    let result = this._getCommonFormControlModel(aStrangeObject)
    result = result.concat(DBEntity.getIdFormControlModel('id', aStrangeObject))
    // console.log('getEditFormControlModel:', result)

    return result
}

onRowClicked(row: any) {
    this.logger.debug('-----> Row clicked', row);
    this.currentEntity = new Branch().deserialize(row);
    if (this.entityEditFormCtlModelArray === undefined) {
    this.entityEditFormCtlModelArray = this._getEditFormControlModel(row);
    // console.log('On formControlModel creation---', this.entityEditFormCtlModel);
    this.entityEditFormGroup = this.formService.createFormGroup(this.entityEditFormCtlModelArray);
    // console.log('Created formModel', this.entityEditFormCtlModel);
    // TODO: Correct a bug that first time the row is clicked values are wrong
    }
    // reassign values TODO make me abstract!!
    const toUpdate = {
    'id': row.id,
    'name': row.name,
    };
    // console.log('update only---', toUpdate);
    this._updateEditFormFields(toUpdate);
    // Set selected branch for consumptionSector (childEntity)
    this.childService.parentEntity = this.currentEntity;
}

sampleAddButtonClicked() {
    // Constants.SAMPLE_BRANCHES_JSON_DATA.forEach( (entity) => {
    //   console.log('sampleAddButtonClicked', entity);
    //   this.buttonAddEntityClicked(entity);
    // });
}

} // end class

import {ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {DynamicFormControlModel, DynamicFormService, DynamicInputModel} from '@ng-dynamic-forms/core';
import {LoggerService} from '../../logger/logger.service';
import {MessageService} from '../../services/message.service';
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {SseEntityDataSource} from '../../datasources/sse-entity-data-source';
import {UserMessage, UserMessageType} from '../../entities/user.message';
import {Constants} from '../../Constants';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {OnInit, ViewChild, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DBEntity} from '../../entities/d-b-entity';
import {SseEntityService} from '../../services/sse.entity.service';
import { StringHelper } from 'src/app/helpers/StringHelper';
import { ReloadableComponent } from './reloadable.component';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

### abstract class EntityListComponent

```
export abstract class EntityListComponent<D extends DBEntity> extends ReloadableComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnInit {

protected _currentEntity: D = null // Set to null and not undefined cause of list.component.html tests for it  reason explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript
protected abstract displayedColumnsArray: Array<string>; // Gives the order of the columns
public entitiesListTitle = this.constructor.name

// FORMS
entityAddFormGroup: FormGroup;
entityAddFormCtlModelArray: DynamicFormControlModel[];
entityEditFormGroup: FormGroup;
entityEditFormCtlModelArray: DynamicFormControlModel[];

// DATA TABLE variables
dataSource: SseEntityDataSource<D>;
selectionModel = new SelectionModel<D>(true, []);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

constructor(
    protected router: Router,
    public messageService: MessageService,
    protected logger: LoggerService,
    protected route: ActivatedRoute,
    protected entitiesService: SseEntityService<D>,
    protected formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public formService: DynamicFormService,
    iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    public entityPrototype: DBEntity,
    // private location: Location
) {
    super(
    iconRegistry,
    sanitizer,
    )
    if (entityPrototype === undefined || entityPrototype == null){
    throw new Error('constructor error, create me in the caller entityPrototype!')
    }
}

/**
* calls this._getAddFormControlModel() and adds it to entityAddFormCtlModelArray
*/
public ngOnInit() {
    // console.debug('ngOnInit called')
    if (this.entityPrototype === undefined){
    throw new Error('entity-list.component->ngOnInit-> this.entityPrototype is undefined, set it into constructor of descendant')
    }
    this.entitiesListTitle = StringHelper.camelCaseToSpaces(this.constructor.name.replace('Component', ''))


    this.dataSource = new SseEntityDataSource<D>(this.logger, this.entitiesService, this, this.entityPrototype);
    this.setMessageService();
    this.entityAddFormCtlModelArray = this._getAddFormControlModel(this.entityPrototype);
    this.entityAddFormGroup = this.formService.createFormGroup(this.entityAddFormCtlModelArray);
}

protected abstract _getCommonFormControlModel(aStrangeObject: DBEntity): DynamicFormControlModel[]
protected abstract _getAddFormControlModel(aStrangeObject: DBEntity): DynamicFormControlModel[]

public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
//    this.cdr.detectChanges();
//    this.dataSource.loadEntities()
}

/**
*
* @param aParentService
* @param anEntitiesResult$  if you want these entities to be loaded from a different result from entitiesService.findEntities() give it
*/
public loadEntities (aParentService?: SseEntityService<DBEntity>, anEntitiesResult$?: Observable<D[]>) {
    if (aParentService !== undefined){
    let lParamValue = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('parentId')
    if (lParamValue === undefined||lParamValue === null) { // Load default from API
        console.debug('loadEntities->parentEntityId param not found, loading from defaults')
        aParentService.getSelected().subscribe(lData => {
            aParentService.currentEntity = aParentService.entityPrototype.deserialize(lData)
            this.dataSource.loadEntities(anEntitiesResult$)
        },
        lError => {
            this.messageService.add(new UserMessage('loadEntities Error:', lError, UserMessageType.Error));
        })
    } else {
        console.debug('loadEntities-> param parentId:', lParamValue)
        aParentService.currentEntity = aParentService.entityPrototype.deserialize(aParentService.entityPrototype)
        aParentService.currentEntity.id = parseInt(lParamValue)
        this.dataSource.loadEntities()
    }

    } else {
    this.dataSource.loadEntities()
    }
}

public loadEntitiesFromDatasArray (anEntitiesArray: D[]) {
    this.dataSource.loadEntitiesFromDatasArray(anEntitiesArray)
}

get currentEntity(): D {
    return this._currentEntity;
}

set currentEntity(value: D) {
    this._currentEntity = value;
    this.entitiesService.currentEntity = value;
}

/**
* Require dataSource not null
*/
public loadDatasourceWithPaginator() {
    // Init currentEntityId
    try {
    this.dataSource.loadEntities();
    } catch (e) {
    this.messageService.add(new UserMessage('Error loading entities', e, UserMessageType.Error));
    throw e;
    }
}

public applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}


/**
* Require dataSource not null
*/
public setMessageService() {
    this.dataSource.messagesForUsers$.subscribe(
    usrMessage => {
        this.messageService.add(usrMessage);
    }
    );
}


abstract onRowClicked(row: any): void;

public buttonAddEntityClicked(dataValues: any) {
    console.debug('buttonAddEntityClicked-------->from Entitylist.components dataValues:', dataValues);
    let lEntity = this.entityPrototype.deserialize(dataValues, false)
    console.debug('buttonAddEntityClicked-------->from Entitylist.components lEntity:', lEntity);
    console.debug('buttonAddEntityClicked-------->from Entitylist.components lEntity.toJSON():', lEntity.toJSON());

    this.entitiesService.addEntityFromFormData(lEntity.toJSON()).subscribe(
    lData => {
        const msg = `Entity added successfully`;
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage(msg, lData, UserMessageType.Info));
        this.afterEntityUpdatedSucessful()
    },
    lError => {
        const msg = `Entity add Error`;
        console.error('buttonAddEntityClicked->Error:', lError)
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage(msg, lError, UserMessageType.Error));
        throw lError;
    }
    );
}

public afterEntityUpdatedSucessful(){
    this.loadDatasourceWithPaginator();
}


public buttonEditEntityClicked(jsonStringValues: string) {
    this.logger.debug('buttonAddEntityClicked-> from Entitylist.components:', jsonStringValues);
    let lEntity = this.entityPrototype.deserialize(jsonStringValues, false)
    this.logger.debug('buttonEditEntityClicked-> Entitylist.components: jsonStringValues, lEntity:', jsonStringValues, lEntity);

    this.entitiesService.updateEntityFromFormData(lEntity.toJSON()).subscribe(
    lData => {
        const msg = `Entity updated successfully`;
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage(msg, lData, UserMessageType.Info));
        this.afterEntityUpdatedSucessful()
    },
    lError => {
        const msg = `Entity update Error`;
        console.error('buttonEditEntityClicked->Error:', lError)
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage(msg, lError, UserMessageType.Error));
        throw lError;
    }
    );
}


public buttonRemoveSelectedRowsClicked() {
    let toReloadObservable: Observable<Object> = null;
    this.selectionModel.selected.forEach(item => {
    this.logger.debug('Deleting selected item:', item);
    toReloadObservable = this.entitiesService.deleteFromId(item.id);
    toReloadObservable.subscribe(
        data => {
        const msg = `Entity ${item.id} deleted successfully`;
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage(msg, data, UserMessageType.Info));
        this.afterEntityUpdatedSucessful()
        },
        error => {
        const msg = `Error while deleting entity ${item.id}`;
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage(msg, error, UserMessageType.Error));
        throw error;
        }
    );
    });
    this.selectionModel = new SelectionModel<D>(true, []);
    this._currentEntity = null;
    // When all are removed reload data source
}

public onReloadClicked(anEvent) {
    this.loadDatasourceWithPaginator();
}

public buttonMasterToggleClicked() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
    this.selectionModel.clear() :
    this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selectionModel.select(row));
}

public sampleAddButtonClicked() {
    Constants.SAMPLE_COMPANIES_JSON_DATA.forEach( (entity) => {
    // console.log('sampleAddButtonClicked', JSON.stringify(entity));
    this.buttonAddEntityClicked(entity);
    });
}

public isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selectionModel.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.entitiesCount();
    return numSelected === numRows;
}

protected _updateEditFormFields(toUpdate: any) {
    console.log("updateEditFormFields->toUpdate, model", toUpdate, this.entityEditFormCtlModelArray);
    Object.entries(toUpdate).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // console.log('updateEditFormFields->setting key', key, 'value:', value);
    const inputModel = this.formService.findById(key, this.entityEditFormCtlModelArray) as DynamicInputModel;

    if (inputModel == null) {
        throw new Error('updateEditFormFields->InputModel is null, key ' + key + ' not found into entityEditFormCtlModel val:' + value );
    }
    inputModel.valueUpdates.next(value as string)//If not reloading recreate the formGroup with this.entityAddFormGroup = this.formService.createFormGroup(this.entityAddFormCtlModelArray);
    // inputModel.valueUpdates.subscribe(value => console.log('new value assigned to field: ', newVal));
    // inputModel.disabledUpdates.next(true);
    });
}



}
```

[Changing the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991372/angular-error-uncaught-in-promise-at-webpackasynccontext-eval-at-src) of imports into `app.module.ts` into `imports` with `AppRouteModule,` @ the end didn't solve my problem

### Update (20190222)

seems to be related to [this bug](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/issues/924)

Comment: Please post the html and css also

Comment: You should also post the Component code as well... depending on how that data table is created it could be any number of things. The css doesn’t seem relevant to answering the question imo.

Comment: @dileepkumarjami  done thx

Comment: @nclarx done thx

Answer (score 0):

Related to [this issue](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/issues/924), see [workaround](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/issues/924#issuecomment-460630639)